# How to Send Push Notifications Using Group Messaging Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating a college Android application where faculty choose the specific course and send them assignment notification but how i do that i don't Know... please help me..

Comment: subscribe to topic and then send using that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe topic from Android app. Send notifications to that topic so it will received to all users who has subscribed it.

Sample code subscribe top from Android app.

> `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");`

Send message to this topic from server-
URL- `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`
Body-

```
{
  "to": "/topics/news",
  "data": {
    "message": "Message to user",
    "title":"title of message",
    "sender":"sender name"
   }
}
```

headers- api key from firebase

Rest you need write code from Android and Server side. 
You can also send notifications form Firebase console as well.

Comment: Any example if i can see so it would be really useful..! I want to that there is section in faculty where faculty choose the specific course and then type the documentation about assignment and then send it ..and those student who made his profile and mentioned that particular course can view the assignment (get assignment notification) i don't know how to approach to this scenario...

Comment: Create topic for each course. Those student opted specific course subscribed that topic. or in notification title/sender you can send identifier for course you want send notification and show notification those student who has subscribed to that particular course.

Comment: Sir ,,,I got you lil bit but on the other hand  it's gone above me.... but thanks a lot for your concern....